# oracle 19c lead ожидается number получено date

Tags: sql, oracle19c

Oracle 19c
Проблема с функцией lead

```
create table test_tbl (id number, datebegin date);
merge into test_tbl t
using (
select
lead(r.datebegin,1,to_date('31.12.5999','dd.mm.yyyy')) OVER (ORDER BY 1 ) datebegin
from test_tbl r
) s
on (t.datebegin = s.datebegin)
when matched then
update set id = 1
```

Получаю ошибку: ожидается number получено date на строке с lead
Если не указывать значение по умолчанию, то работает.

Проверил на 11.2.0.4, значение по умолчанию работает.
Это причуды 19 версии?
Как это обойти?

upd:В итоге решил так - все выражение lead конвертировал в строку, потом обратно в дату и обернул в nvl

Comment: Таблица назначения имеет 2 поля в структуре, причём первое NUMBER, тогда как подзапрос - только одно поле, причём DATE. И при этом WHEN NOT MATCHED отсутствует. Чё б ему не ругаться-то?

Comment: @Akina а зачем WHEN NOT MATCHED? конструкция же и без него валидная. По поводу полей - в случае совпадения datebegin в подзапросе и datebegin в основной таблице апдейтятся записи в основной таблице. Что тут некорректно? к тому же это только пример

Comment: Посмотрел, на 11 действительно все работает и в таком случае действительно похоже на глюк в версии. Интересно, а просто сам запрос который в using работает или только в составе merge глючит. Я бы попробовал убрать default у lead и написать его в `on (t.datebegin = nvl(s.datebegin, to_date ...))`

Comment: @Mike, подзапрос работает, глючит в составе merge. В итоге решил так: все выражение lead конвертировал в строку, потом обратно в дату и обернул в nvl. У меня nvl в условии on не получится, т.к. выше я привел только пример, а основной запрос трехэтажный и там так не получится